# Scroll, instead of move cursor, if at end of file

Tags: vim, vi, vimrc

I find myself unintentionally hitting `j` (or some other downward cursor movement key) when I'm at the bottom of a file. Then the next thing I do is to hit `Ctrl-E` to scroll the current line up - I may even just hit `zt` to move the current line to the top of the window.

My question is: Is there a way I could configure vim to automatically scroll for me (I am ok with just using `Ctrl-W` in this case) when I hit `j` at the last line of a file?

I know [there's already a similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/331604/naturally-scroll-past-end-of-last-line-in-vim), but the answer is to persist the cursor in the middle of the screen, which is not what I'm looking to do.

Comment: Consider using [vi.se] for questions on Vim!

Answer (score 0):

You can use an "expr" mapping to check whether you're on the last line of the buffer and map `j` to `<C-e>` in that case.

```
nnoremap <expr> j line('.') ==# line('$') ? '<C-e>' : 'j'
```

If you want this to also work the same way on Visual mode, then repeat the command with `xnoremap` as well.

```
xnoremap <expr> j line('.') ==# line('$') ? '<C-e>' : 'j'
```